Greatest and least fixed points for fixed point logic.
I am trying to do what this question did and build an understanding of fixed point constructions in logic.
More specifically, I am reading this presentation and attempting to make sense of the construction that they write as:
$$ [\text{lfp}_{R, \vec{x}}\varphi](\vec{t}) $$
Where $\vec{t}$ is a tuple of terms of the same length as $\vec{x}$, both of which have length equal to the arity of $R$. $R$ is a predicate-valued variable. $R$ is constrained to appear positively in $\varphi$.
Let me define higher-order logic with repetition (HOLR) as follows:

The formulas of higher-order logic.
An iteration construction on unary functions $f^k(x)$ which is equivalent to $f(\cdots f(x)\cdots)$ with $k$ copies of $x$.
I also give myself a sort of natural numbers that can be eliminated in the iteration construction.

I don't have a source for HOLR, but I claim that its possible semanticses (full and Henkin)  are relatively understandable. In any case, my only goal here is to try to paraphrase away $\text{lfp}$ into something that I'm already familiar with.
Anyhoo, using HOLR I can come up with one possible paraphrase of $\text{lfp}$, namely:

$\forall R \mathop. f(R) = \varphi(R)$ where $S = T$ is paraphrased away as $\forall \vec{x} \mathop. S(\vec{x}) = T(\vec{x})$
$\forall k \mathop. f^k(\top)(\vec{t})$ where $\top$ is the always-true predicate of the same arity as $R$.

In this translation, $f$ is a fresh constant symbol and $1$ is an auxiliary hypothesis that is presupposed alongside the translation of the original formula rather than asserted.
My construction ends up being similar to the construction given in the first two minutes of this lecture by Thomas Studer.
The thing that set off alarm bells in my head, thinking my fixed point construction is capturing the wrong thing is that the speaker called their construction the greatest fixed point.
At 27m13s, we can see two rules:

$\frac{\Gamma\{A^k(\bot)\} \;\;\text{for some $k$}}{\Gamma\{\mu k\}}$
$\frac{\Gamma\{A^k(\top)\} \;\;\text{for all $k$}}{\Gamma\{\nu k\}}$

Which makes me think that maybe replacing $(2)$ in my construction with something like $\exists k \mathop. f^k(\bot)(\vec{t}) $ will do the trick, but I am not sure.
Anyway, my question is twofold.

Is my construction the greatest fixed point?
Is there a simpler way to get at the truth conditions of the least fixed point operator?

